# Pass parameters to '.index' controller function using Laravel resourceful routing

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I'm using resourceful routing and I need to pass a parameter to the `index` function of the controller.

```
public function index($id){
// do something with $id
}
```

If I try to create a form like (say $user->id = 3):

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('scopes.index', $user->id))) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

I get in the html this link:
`http://alumni.app/scopes?3` which is not good because it doesn't follow the URI for that named route. So, how should I proceed?

Discussion: I'm trying to load a list of `scopes` depending on the current user. I made an independent 
`scopes` controller.

Comment: Route::resource's index route doesn't take a parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `index` action of a resource controller / route doesn't take any parameters by design.

For *filtering* I suggest you use query parameters.

```
/scope?userId=1

{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('scopes.index', array('userId' => $user->id)))) }}
```

Another approach would be [nested resources](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) (scroll down a bit)

If you nest the scope resource inside user you could get this kind of url:

```
/user/1/scope
```

Comment: Thanks @lukasgeiter I'll be nesting the routes for a better design.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate route instead:

```
Route::get('scopes/{id}', ['as' => 'scopes.index', 'uses' => 'ScopeController@index']);
```

And exclude it from your resource route:

```
Route::resource('scopes', 'ScopesController', ['except' => ['index']]);
```